# How to refetch fullCalendar(jQuery plugin) from colorbox iframe?

Tags: jquery, json, iframe, fullcalendar, colorbox

My question is how to [refetch events](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/) to fullCalendar from an iframe? The calendar is on the main page, and the user can edit the calender trough a colorbox popup (iframe). When the user saves the changes i want the calender to reload the events trough the json file.

i have tried:

`$('#kalender1', window.parent.document).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`

And its not working.

/Linus

***SOLVED***

I solved it.. It has to be:

`parent.$('#SELECTOR').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`

instead of

`$('#SELECTOR', window.parent.document).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.. It has to be:

`parent.$('#SELECTOR').fullCalendar('refetchEvents')`

instead of

`$('#SELECTOR', window.parent.document).fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`